# Can't load jQuery (error in minified jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with loading jQuery on a website, I'm using a minified version in my own vendor file and I get this syntax error in the console :

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-undefined*=]
    at Function.se.error (scripts.js?qpcd43:2)
    at se.tokenize (scripts.js?qpcd43:2)
    at se.select (scripts.js?qpcd43:2)
    at Function.se [as find] (scripts.js?qpcd43:2)
    at E.fn.init.find (scripts.js?qpcd43:2)
    at new E.fn.init (scripts.js?qpcd43:2)
    at E (scripts.js?qpcd43:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js?qpcd43:77)
    at Function.each (scripts.js?qpcd43:2)
    at E.fn.init.each (scripts.js?qpcd43:2)
```

There is an older version of JQuery on this site which I can't remove, I put a noconflict at the top of my HTML file before loading my vendor libraries and my JS. Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue in jQuery itself. I'm going to make assumptions based on the error (as that's all you've shown) and state that the error is because a selector in a jQuery object somewhere in your code is invalid.

You most likely have a selector that looks something like one of these two:

```js
$('[data-undefined*=' + foo + ']');
$(`[data-undefined*=${foo}]`);
```

The error you're seeing is because `foo` is empty or undefined, so the selector becomes this:

```css
[data-undefined*=]
```

This is invalid as you've not provided a value to look for in the attribute.

Comment: I have this in my code : `var constructedAttrName = '[data-' + $(this).parent().attr('name') + '*='+ (this).attr('value') +'];`. Do you think it could be the cause of the problem ?

Comment: First `(this)` should ne `$(this)` and `.attr('value')` needs to be `.val()`. Try this: `var constructedAttrName = '[data-' + $(this).parent().attr('name') + '*=' + $(this).val() + '];`